# Bigcommerce API: Getting a null return when creating product image

Tags: php, curl, bigcommerce

I have built a PHP script using the Bigcommerce PHP Api class and so far it's all good. I can create/fetch products, categories, brands and etc... However I am now trying to send a request to add an image to a product but getting a null reply from the curl post request. My image sits on an external server so the "image_file" field value is set to the full URL of the image. My request is as follows:

```
[23-04-2014 01:09:51] https://{my_store_url}/api/v2/products/{product id}/images - Request:
stdClass Object
(
    [image_file] => {my external domain}/{file path}.png
)
```

I have checked and the image URL does work, I actually added the image manually via the BC control panel from this external URL and that also worked.

Any ideas? Seems like a bug with the Bigcommerce API...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Image is read only attribute unfortunately.

Per: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products#create-product

POST /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products

Read-only Properties
The following properties of the product are read-only. If one or more of these properties are included in the request, it will be rejected.

calculated_price
brand
images
discount_rules
configurable_fields
custom_fields
videos
skus
rules
option_set
options
tax_class
Requirement